# how to download youtube videos with php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to download Youtube videos using this Perl script:
[JWZ-Youtube-dl](https://www.jwz.org/hacks/youtubedown) 
by executing it using PHP script like this:

```
<?php

   exec('perl youtubedown --title vidtitle https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JQH3G0cCtY');

?>
```

that code works fine on localhost, but it's NOT working on live server, and when trying to catch the $output of exec, I got this:

```
Array ( [0] => Content-Type: text/html [1] => Status: 500 [2] => [3] => "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [14] => [15] => [16] =>
ERROR: no URL specified for CGI [17] => )
```

**NOTE1**: I'm able to download videos using that 'Bash command' in local machine and in server using ssh connection(using both Root || Non-root account).

**NOTE2**: Other Perl scripts run successfully.

**NOTE3**: Other php exec() scripts run successfully too.

Does anyone know how to fix that, or another way to download youtube videos using php?

Thank you.

Comment: hello,
yes 'youtubedown' is in the CWD of my running PHP process, and I have tried before to put it in cgi-bin but same.
Yes Perl in PATH and I can use it with other scripts,
I have tried 755 and 777 permmessions but still the same,
and for #! I'm using what my cpanel says: 
`#!/usr/bin/perl
use cPanelUserConfig;`

I have tried explicit full path for both Perl & Perl' script
`exec('/usr/bin/perl  /home/mysite/public_html/cgi-bin/youtubedown --title vidname https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JQH3G0cCtY 2>&1', $output, $result);`

Comment: Why would you run that from a PHP program?

Comment: "by executing it using PHP sctipt like this" why though? You don't state if youtubedown operates successfully on the remote host from the command line. Remove PHP from the equation

Comment: this is just a part of a platform, which is written using php..

Comment: works fine for me, as a php script or running command line. no errors. Check your server log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decide to use [Youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/), then execute it using PHP like this:

```
<?php
   exec('youtube-dl -f 22 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93lrosBEW-Q');
?>
```

it works like a charm.
thank you.